# how to use ajax here to update a database table after clicking on remove button

Tags: php, ajax

I have a php page generating and displaying products , there's a p tag with onclick function attached i need after clicking this p tag to update my database table 
i use a function written with javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPCUa.png)

after clicking on X and confirming delete i need to to sent post request with ajax to update my orders database table

```
<?php $exhibtion_selected = $define_class->return_exhibtions_ids($employee_id,$id);
            if($exhibtion_selected){
                echo "<div class='row clearfix'>"; 
                foreach($exhibtion_selected as $single){
                    $one = $define_node->front_node_data($single->product_id,'post', null, null,$lang_info->id, null, null, null, null,  null, "one");
                    //echo $single->product_id ;
                    $summary = strip_tags($one->summary);
                    echo "
                          <div class='col-md-4 product-outer product-reserved'>
                          <p class='fa fa-times product-remove'  onclick='removeThis(this.parentNode)'></p>
                          <div class='col-md-12 product-image'>
                          <img src='media-library/$one->cover_image' alt=''> 
                          </div>"; 
                    echo "<div class='col-md-12 product-text give-graydarker-bg'>
                         <ul class='product-text-inner'>
                          <li class='clearfix'>
                            <p class='col-md-12 product-area-lg product-company'>$one->prod_company</p>
                            <p class='col-md-12 product-area-sm product-quan'>($single->sold_quantity)</p>
                           </li>
                           <li class='clearfix'>
                            <p class='col-md-12 product-area-55 product-name'>$one->prod_title</p>
                            <p class='col-md-12 product-area-45 product-code'>$one->prod_code</p>
                           </li>
                           <li class='clearfix'>
                            <p class='col-md-12 product-size'>$one->prod_size</p>
                            <div class='col-md-12  product-price'>
                              <p class='col-md-12 product-price-before'>$one->prod_before_discount <span class='currency'>EGP</span></p>
                              <p class='col-md-12 product-price-after'>$one->prod_price<span class='currency'>EGP</span></p>
                            </div>
                          </li>
                          <li class='clearfix'>
                           <p class='col-md-12 product-description'>$summary</p>
                          </li>
                          </ul>
                          </div>"; 



                    echo "</div>";


                }
                echo "</div>";
             }
```

?>

Comment: Writing code would be a good start... We're not here to bang out code for you, or teach you how to write code. YOU write some code, we'll (maybe) try help fix it.

Comment: foreach($exhibtion_selected as $single){
$one = $define_node->front_node_data($single->product_id,'post', null, null,$lang_info->id, null, null, null, null,  null, "one");
$summary = strip_tags($one->summary);
echo "<p class='fa fa-times product-remove'  onclick='removeThis(this.parentNode)'></p>
                              <div class='col-md-12 product-image'>
                              <img src='media-library/$one->cover_image' alt=''> 
                              </div>"; }

Comment: @EmadRashad Please post that code in your original post and properly format it by selecting it and clicking CTRL + K on your keyboard.